What is this usage of 回った?

The character is a bit drunk and a friend is helping him home. I guess he's having troubles walking? "You rotated with a time difference"? Or there is another meaning of  回った here?

回る here means "to take effect" (see definition 5). Basically it means to get drunk. The way it's used here isn't that common; you will hear the phrase 酔いが回る  or 酒が回る (to get drunk, buzzed, tipsy) more often. Think of 回る as the liquor "circulating" in your blood.
Here the line means "it took a while for the liquor to kick in".
